# How to create temporary table in sql server 2008 R2 database?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2

I am new to `SQL SERVER` and I am using `C#` as language.
Now I want to create a temporary table that should be independent of my current database and use that in datatable to retrieve my data from that datatable.

Answer (score 0):

The normal way to create a temporary table in SQL Server is to preface the table name with a # sign. The table will persist for the duration on the connection and then disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar question with answers that can be usefull.

[Create a temporary table like a current table in SQL Server 2005/2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1689623/create-a-temporary-table-like-a-current-table-in-sql-server-2005-2008)